# How to share variables between classes?

Tags: python, django

I have 2 classes which require the other one to either run a function or call an object from the each other. The problem is that the object of one is "not defined" causing the other to not be able run the function. This throws the an exception and makes it revert to the default value which I want to be updated. Seems like a chicken and egg problem but I am sure this is normal in Python and I just do not understand how to solve it.

```
class CreateSettings:

    def __init__(self, name, default):
        self.name = name
        self.default = default

    def getvalue(self):
        print(float(Settings.objects.values(
                str(self.name)).last().get(str(self.name))))
        try:
            self.default = float(Settings.objects.values(
                str(self.name)).last().get(str(self.name)))
            return self.default
        except (NameError, AttributeError):
            return self.default


man_serv_bonus_default = CreateSettings('manager_service_bonus_max', 300.00)


class Settings(models.Model):

    manager_service_bonus_max = models.CharField(
        max_length=16, default=man_serv_bonus_default.getvalue())
```

The `Settings` class is used by the user to update settings through a form. The `CreateSettings` class will be used to initially set the values in the form and update the values after any time a user has submitted the form.

How do I get around this?

Comment: So basically when  you give user form for updation you want it to be pre-filled with some values isn't it ?If that's the case what you are looking for is `bounded form`

Comment: Yes. Exactly what I am doing. I did not know of bounded form. I will look into it. Thank you very much.